# Components of vector in symbol computation

Tags: symbolic

I want to define a $3d$ vector $\gamma^{j}_{i}$ (here $i$ is the space node index, and $j$ is the time node index, in other words, suppose we have a time-space grid, and $\gamma$ is the vector variable in this gird).

Here is a simple example, if $\gamma^{j}_{i}$ and $\gamma^{j+1}_{i}$ have some relationship, um, like $\gamma^{j+1}_{i} - \gamma^{j}_{i} = [1,2,3]^T$, can i write in MMA to get the components expression?

I have tried to define $\gamma^{j+1}_i$ in components form like $\gamma^{j+1}_{1,i}$,$\gamma^{j+1}_{2,i}$ ,$\gamma^{j+1}_{3,i}$.

So in MMA, `Subscript[\[Gamma], i]^(j + 1) =  Transpose[{Subscript[\[Gamma], 1, i]^(j + 1), Subscript[\[Gamma], 2,  i]^(j + 1), Subscript[\[Gamma], 3, i]^(j + 1)}]`

But MMA tells me the tag power in $\gamma^{j+1}_i$ protect! I know I can define $\gamma$ like $\gamma = \{a,b,c\}^T$.

The reason I want to use subscript and superscript here is to make the output more intuitive When the vector variable has a complicated relationship.

Can I Let the MMA symbol computation result be what you see is what you get? in this example is $$\gamma^{j+1}_{1,i} - \gamma^{j}_{1,i} = 1, $$ $$\gamma^{j+1}_{2,i} - \gamma^{j}_{2,i} = 2,$$ $$ \gamma^{j+1}_{3,i} - \gamma^{j}_{3,i} = 3 $$

Any comments will be very appreciated, and wish you have a good day!

Comment: Better use ˋIndexedˋ instead if ˋSubscriptˋ. It also works with arrays and then performs the actual indexing.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thank you, i see, `Indexed[\[Gamma], {i, j + 1}] - 
  Indexed[\[Gamma], {i, j}] - {1, 2, 3} // MatrixForm` can be get more intuitive result. I think `Indexed` will be very useful in tensor analysis!

Comment: oh, I'm wrong,  `Indexed` is getting the components and no longer a vector, so the above my code is not the right answer. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica notation, `^` means raising to a power, so for a certain $j$, say $j = 1$, `Subscript[\[Gamma], i]^2 = Subscript[\[Gamma], i] * Subscript[\[Gamma], i]` and so on.  This is why the assignment fails.

One way around can be to define a vector function defined on integer values of arguments, such as `g[i,j]`.  Then it is possible to write things like

```
g[i_, j_ + 1 ] = g[ i ,j ] + { 1,2,3 }
```

Note that Mathematica does not distinguish between column and row vectors ([a tutorial on this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebra.html#31071)).